# How can I change passive into an active form in the following sentence?

Tags: grammar, passive-voice, active-voice, active-vs-passive

Grammarly is displaying passive voice misuse in this sentence?

A mobile-friendly shopping website ***was developed*** to study e-commerce compatibilities in smartphones.

Comment: Your example is called a 'short passive' because there is no internalised complement (agent). The active version would be "X developed a mobile-friendly shopping website to study e-commerce compatibilities in smartphones". It seems OK to me.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, we have to assume a doer . Let's say the doer is Developer. Now the active voice of this sentence is "Developer developed a mobile -friendly shopping website to study e-commerce compatibilies in smartphones.

Comment: You've just repeated what I said in comments.

Comment: Yes, that is good. The purpose of comments is to enable questions to be answered. If you comment contains an answer, you should expect an answer to repeat what was said in comments!